# Allow workflow to send email using exchange pickup directory

Tags: dynamics-crm-4, exchange-server-2007

I have a workflow running on the CRM server the tries to write a file to the pickup directory on exchange (a seperate server)

the workflow runs in the CRM async Service which used Network Service credentails.

writting the file fails due to permissions.

the pickup directory is set to allow Network Service full control

this is the code that send the message

```
        /*snip - code that reads crm and puts valuse in to a template and builds email */

        SmtpClient SmtpMail = new SmtpClient("MyServerName");
        SmtpMail.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory;
        SmtpMail.PickupDirectoryLocation = @"\\MyServerName\c$\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\TransportRoles\Pickup\";

        SmtpMail.Send(mail);
```

we cannot use a crm email activity because the massage has to come from a genertic account that is not a CRM user.

any idea what permissions might be wrong?

Comment: Have you granted the permission for the "Network Service" account or the computer account of the server which runs the async service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the CRM Async Service definitely running as the Network Account? Also you have you tried opening a browser window as the service account and performing the action manually (to rule out a simple permissions issue)?

As another approach you could try sending the email from:

- A system user record that represents the 'generic administrator account'.
- Or to save yourself a license from a queue (queues can also have mail boxes).

This way the email can still be tracked in Crm and you dont have to worry about the issues you are currently having - I would say this is a better solution that doesnt require custom development.

Comment: hmm, didnt think of using Queues.   i'll give that a go.